# listview when refreshed , not updating the data android

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, refresh

I am using custom layout listview with custom adapter. I am also using [Pull to refresh listview](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) library

When I pull to refresh the UI changes are notifiable,but actual update in the listview is not happening

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
private ListView listView;
PullToRefreshListView refreshable_listView;
private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsList;
String index_th="0";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, container,false);

            //karthik
            refreshable_listView = (PullToRefreshListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

            refreshable_listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {

                @Override
                public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                                                  
                    new GetList().execute(index_th);
                }


            });

            listView=refreshable_listView.getRefreshableView();
}
private class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        String jsonStr;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Local_newsList;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Local_newsList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();



            // Showing progress dialog
            /*dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout._wait_dialog);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            dialog.show();*/

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            if (NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity()) == true) {

                //Log.d("index count for array", params[0]);
                if(Integer.parseInt(params[0])==0){
                    //Log.d("index count for array","Rweached");
                    newsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                }


                // Creating service handler class instance
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(All_link.HOME_DATA_URL + "/"+params[0]+"/"+ icount,
                        ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        news = jsonObj.getJSONArray(All_link.TAG_NEWS);


                        err = jsonObj.getString(All_link.TAG_ERROR);
                        String more = jsonObj.getString(All_link.TAG_MORE);

                        Log.e("------>Error",String.valueOf(err));
                        Log.e("------>More",String.valueOf(more));
                        if(more.equals("0")){

                            load_more = 0;

                        }else{

                            load_more = 1;
                        }

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++) {

                            //karthik



                            JSONObject segments_list = news.getJSONObject(i);

                            for (int plates_count = 0; plates_count < segments_list
                                    .length(); plates_count++) {


                                String plates = "";
                                if (plates_count == 3) {
                                    plates = String.valueOf("banner_image");

                                    JSONObject segments_plates = segments_list
                                            .getJSONObject(plates);

                                    //String flag = "banner_image";
                                    String id = segments_plates
                                            .getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_ID);
                                    String banner_no = segments_plates
                                            .getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_NO);

                                    String banner_image;

                                    if(segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL)==""){

                                        banner_image = All_link.TAG_NO_IMAGE;
                                    }else{

                                        banner_image = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL);
                                    }

                                    String banner_status = segments_plates
                                            .getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_STATUS);


                                    // tmp hashmap for single news
                                    HashMap<String, String> news_hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                    // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                    // value
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_ID, id);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_NO,
                                            banner_no);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL,
                                            banner_image);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_STATUS,
                                            banner_status);
                                    /*news_hashmap
                                            .put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_FLAG, flag);*/

                                    // adding contact to contact list



                                    newsList.add(news_hashmap);


                                    //karthik newsList

                                    //Local_newsList.add(news_hashmap);


                                    addSeparatorItem();
                                } else {
                                    plates = String.valueOf(plates_count + 1);

                                    JSONObject segments_plates = segments_list
                                            .getJSONObject(plates);

                                    if(segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TYPE).equals("2")){

                                        //type_of_news = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TYPE);
                                        addSeparatorItem_for_live();
                                    }                                   

                                    String id = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_ID);
                                    String news_title = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TITLE);
                                    String news_desc = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_DESC);
                                    String segment = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_SEGMENT);
                                    String plate = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_PLATE);

                                    String img ="";
                                    if(segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL).equals("")){

                                        img = All_link.TAG_NO_IMAGE;

                                    }else{

                                        img = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL);
                                    }


                                    HashMap<String, String> news_hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                    // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                    // value
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_ID, id);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TITLE, news_title);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_DESC, news_desc);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_SEGMENT, segment);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_PLATE, plate);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL, img);
                                    //news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_FLAG, flag);
                                    // adding contact to contact list

                                    newsList.add(news_hashmap);



                                    //karthik newsList

                                    //Local_newsList.add(news_hashmap);

                                    int val = 0;
                                    int val2 = 1;
                                    val = (Integer.parseInt(segment)%2)==0 ? val:val2;

                                    if((Integer.parseInt(segment)%2)!=0){
                                        Log.e("--->CHECKING ODD EVEN", String.valueOf(val));
                                        addSeparatorItem();
                                        addSeparatorItem_for_alternate();   
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Local_newsList=null;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Network Error", "Internet Connection Error");
                error_flag = 1;
                // error = "Internet Connection Error";

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);                            

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                         refreshable_listView.onRefreshComplete();


                }
            });

            super.onPostExecute(result);            
}
```

MyCustomAdapter.java

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        Boolean result;
        private final LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        public ImageLoader imageLoader;

        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR_ALTERNATE = 2;
        private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 3;
        private int live_type = 0;


        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            activity = a;
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            int separtorValue;
            int pos = mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR: TYPE_ITEM;
            live_type = mSeparatorsSet_live_layout.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR: TYPE_ITEM;
            if(pos==1){
                //Log.e("--->if called- position->", String.valueOf(position));
                if(mSeparatorsSet_alternate_layout.contains(position)){

                    //Log.e("--->if called-->", String.valueOf(position));
                    separtorValue = 2;
                }else{

                    separtorValue = 1;  
                }


            }else{

                separtorValue = 0;
            }


            return separtorValue;
        }


        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            Log.e("--->TYPE_MAX_COUNT called-->", String.valueOf(TYPE_MAX_COUNT));
            return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return newsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
            return newsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            NewsViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);

            Log.e("--->SHISHIR-->", String.valueOf(live_type));

            /*System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView
                    + " type = " + type);
**/
            //Log.e("--->SHISHIR-->", String.valueOf(position) + " -->live"+String.valueOf(mSeparatorsSet_live_layout.first()));



            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new NewsViewHolder();

                 //Log.e("--itempostion", String.valueOf(getItem(type)));

                switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:




                    if (CURRENT_THEME==1) {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                                R.layout.theme_one_row_small, null);
                    }

                    else{
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                                R.layout.theme_one_row_small_new, null);
                    }




                    holder.img_flag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_live_flag);
                    holder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fid);
                    holder.live = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.live);
                    holder.flag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
                    holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.title);

                    holder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.list_image);

                    imageLoader
                            .DisplayImage(
                                    com.rb.library.All_link.IMAGE_URI_BANNER
                                            + newsList.get(position).get(
                                                    All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL),
                                    holder.img);

                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR_ALTERNATE:





                    if (CURRENT_THEME==1) {
                        convertView = mInflater
                                .inflate(R.layout.theme_one_row_big, null);
                    }

                    else{
                        convertView = mInflater
                                .inflate(R.layout.theme_one_row_big_new, null);
                    }



                    holder.flag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

                    holder.img_flag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_live_flag);
                    holder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fid);
                    holder.live = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.live);
                    holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.title);
                    holder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.list_image);


                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater
                            .inflate(R.layout.theme_banner, null);
                    holder.flag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
                    holder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fid);
                    holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.title);
                    holder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.list_image);

                    break;


                }


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (NewsViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:

                if(live_type == 1){

                    holder.img_flag.setVisibility(0);
                    holder.live.setText("live");

                }else{

                    holder.live.setText("not_live");
                    holder.img_flag.setVisibility(8);
                }
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(com.rb.library.All_link.IMAGE_URI+ newsList.get(position).get(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL),
                        holder.img);
                holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(newsList.get(position).get(
                        All_link.TAG_ID)));
                holder.flag.setText("normal");

                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR_ALTERNATE:

                if(live_type == 1){

                    holder.img_flag.setVisibility(0);
                    holder.live.setText("live");
                    //Log.e("--itempostion Live", "live");
                }else{

                    holder.live.setText("not_live");
                    holder.img_flag.setVisibility(8);
                }

                imageLoader.DisplayImage(com.rb.library.All_link.IMAGE_URI+ newsList.get(position).get(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL),
                        holder.img);
                holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(newsList.get(position).get(
                        All_link.TAG_ID)));
                holder.flag.setText("normal");

                Log.e("karthik", "karthik "+com.rb.library.All_link.IMAGE_URI+ newsList.get(position).get(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL));

                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                Log.e("--banner Images", com.rb.library.All_link.IMAGE_URI_BANNER
                        + newsList.get(position).get(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL));
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(com.rb.library.All_link.IMAGE_URI_BANNER
                        + newsList.get(position).get(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL),
                        holder.img);
                holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(newsList.get(position).get(
                        All_link.TAG_BANNER_ID)));
                holder.flag.setText(newsList.get(position).get(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL));
                break;
            }





            holder.name.setText(String.valueOf(newsList.get(position).get(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TITLE)));

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Beside your issue onPostExecute() primarily works on Ui Thread and you dont need runOnUiThread inside that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `setAdapter` :

```
 mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);                            
 refreshable_listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: but the UI changes in MyCustomAdapter is not reflecting as per if (CURRENT_THEME)condition

Comment: @KarthikKolanji Sorry, what do you mean? Where do you set the adapter?

Comment: while refreshing the listview data gets empty (blank while page) , then after refreshed the data appears .. can I get help regrading this ?

Comment: @KarthikKolanji Yes, but i think you better create a new questin (thats how SO works, 1 answer 1 question), and explain your current new problem there. You can post your new question's URL here, i will take a look at it

Comment: very much thank you for the help , I was stucked here for whole day . You are LIFE SAVER... .. pLS look in to this post after some time for the new question link

Comment: @KarthikKolanji You welcome :) Btw, sorry its not that i dont want to help you with your new problem, but its how SO works. People that see my answer will be confused if i answered something that not on your **current** question. Just create a new one and let me know